# How do I separate a vector with indexes with spaces into separate indexes in R?

Tags: r, string, vector

Ex: I have this:

x <- c("A B C", "D E", "F", "A D")

And I want this:

x <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can split with `strsplit` on the spaces, `unlist` the `list`, get the `unique` elements and `sort`

```
sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, " "))))
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
```